# Connecting to SQL Server on Linux: tsql works; isql cannot log in

Tags: sql-server, linux, freetds, unixodbc

I am trying to set-up a connection to a SQL server instance using Linux. My FreeTDS setup seems to work, but my unixODBC set-up does not.

Here is what happens when I access the database with tsql:

```
tsql -S STCONNSQLDEV\\RscSwitchboard -U sa_RSCSWITCHBOARD -P password
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
```

Here is what happens when I use isql:

```
isql RscSwitchboard sa_RSCSWITCHBOARD password -v
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[37000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa_RSCSWITCHBOARD'.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

My */etc/freetds/freetds.conf*:

```
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same 
# name is found in the installation directory.  
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings, 
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".  

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;   tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;   dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;   debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;   timeout = 10
;   connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
        text size = 64512

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
        host = symachine.domain.com
        port = 5000
        tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
        host = ntmachine.domain.com
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0

[STCONNSQLDEV\\RscSwitchboard]
host = 192.168.15.12
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

My */etc/odbc.ini*:

```
[RscSwitchboard]
Driver      = FreeTDS
Description = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Trace       = Yes
TraceFile   = /tmp/rscswitchboard
servername  = STCONNSQLDEV\\RscSwitchboard
Database    = RscSwitchboard
Port        = 1433
```

My */etc/odbcinst.ini*:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description    = tdsodbc
Driver         = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so

[ODBC]
DEBUG=1
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/rscswitchboard
```

My tracefile:

```
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.564089][__handles.c][450]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Environment = 0x14b4750
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.564197][SQLAllocHandle.c][364]
                Entry:
                        Handle Type = 2
                        Input Handle = 0x14b4750
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.564254][SQLAllocHandle.c][482]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        Output Handle = 0x14b5080
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.564321][SQLConnect.c][3615]
                Entry:            
                        Connection = 0x14b5080            
                        Server Name = [RscSwitchboard][length = 14 (SQL_NTS)]            
                        User Name = [sa_RSCSWITCHBOARD][length = 17 (SQL_NTS)]            
                        Authentication = [********][length = 8 (SQL_NTS)]
                UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

                DIAG [42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa_RSCSWITCHBOARD'.

                DIAG [S1000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source

[ODBC][5002][1406656337.828774][SQLConnect.c][3983]
                Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.828841][SQLError.c][430]
                Entry:                
                        Connection = 0x14b5080                
                        SQLState = 0x7fff8cbb4b10                
                        Native = 0x7fff8cbb4b0c                
                        Message Text = 0x7fff8cbb4b20                
                        Buffer Length = 500                
                        Text Len Ptr = 0x7fff8cbb4b0a
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.828912][SQLError.c][467]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                    
                        SQLState = S1000                    
                        Native = 0x7fff8cbb4b0c -> 0                    
                        Message Text = [[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source]
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.829032][SQLError.c][430]
                Entry:                
                        Connection = 0x14b5080                
                        SQLState = 0x7fff8cbb4b10                
                        Native = 0x7fff8cbb4b0c                
                        Message Text = 0x7fff8cbb4b20                
                        Buffer Length = 500                
                        Text Len Ptr = 0x7fff8cbb4b0a
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.829098][SQLError.c][467]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]                    
                        SQLState = 37000                    
                        Native = 0x7fff8cbb4b0c -> 18456                    
                        Message Text = [[unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa_RSCSWITCHBOARD'.]
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.829179][SQLError.c][430]
                Entry:                
                        Connection = 0x14b5080                
                        SQLState = 0x7fff8cbb4b10                
                        Native = 0x7fff8cbb4b0c                
                        Message Text = 0x7fff8cbb4b20                
                        Buffer Length = 500                
                        Text Len Ptr = 0x7fff8cbb4b0a
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.829234][SQLError.c][467]
                Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.829284][SQLError.c][510]
                Entry:                
                        Environment = 0x14b4750                
                        SQLState = 0x7fff8cbb4b10                
                        Native = 0x7fff8cbb4b0c                
                        Message Text = 0x7fff8cbb4b20                
                        Buffer Length = 500                
                        Text Len Ptr = 0x7fff8cbb4b0a
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.829332][SQLError.c][547]
                Exit:[SQL_NO_DATA]
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.829423][SQLFreeHandle.c][279]
                Entry:
                        Handle Type = 2
                        Input Handle = 0x14b5080
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.829477][SQLFreeHandle.c][330]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][5002][1406656337.829540][SQLFreeHandle.c][212]
                Entry:
                        Handle Type = 1
                        Input Handle = 0x14b4750
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did Andrei's solution work?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

== freetds.conf

```
[global]
    charset = UTF-8
    client charset = UTF-8
    timeout = 10
    connect timeout = 10

[server_a]
    host = 192.168.15.12
    port = 1433
```

==  /etc/odbc.ini

```
[config_a]
Driver      = FreeTDS
Servername  = server_a
Database    = RscSwitchboard
Port        = 1433
```

$ isql -v config_a sa_RSCSWITCHBOARD password

And if that does not fix it then try the

```
tds version = 7.3
```